# Large Matrix handling in Fortran between multiple routines

Tags: matrix, fortran, fortran90

I have a couple of matrices which are generated in a subroutine, and are used and altered in different parts of the program. Since the matrices are 6-dimensional and get quite large (100^6 is nothing unusual), generating and passing through the routines is not an option.
I open files to read/write with `form=unformatted, access='direct'`

What I am doing at the moment is storing them like this:

```
do i=1,noct
  do j=1,noct
    read_in_some_vector()
    do k=1,ngem**2
      do l=1,nvir**2
        mat(l) = mat(l) * some_vector(k) * some_mat(l,k)
      end do
    end do
    ij=j+(i-1)*noct
    write(unit=iunV,rec=ij) (mat(l),l=1,nvir**2)
  end do
end do
```

To use the matrix, I read it recordwise from the files:

```
    iunC=open_mat_file(mat)

    do i = 1,noct
      do j = 1,noct
        ij=j+(i-1)*noct
          read(unit=iunC,rec=ij) (mat(l),l=1,nvir**2)

          ij = min(i,j) + intsum( max(i,j)-1)

          read_some_vector(vec,rec=ij)

          do_sth = do_sth + ddot(nvir**2,mat,1,vec,1)
      end do
    end do
```

At the moment, noct is a small number (compared to the others). But it will change to a quite huge number, so the size of the matrices will explode. The matrices are (and have to be) double precision, so 8Tb for one matrix is in the realm of possibilities.

The matrices are not sparse, and they are all strictly antisymmetric.

What I can think of is either generate the needed matrix-parts directly in the routines, or clutter the harddrives with huge files.
Both would use up a lot of time (calculating or reading/writing).

Can anybody think of a third way? Or a way to optimize this?

Comment: Can't you declare the matrices in a module and then `use` the matrix from the module in the subroutines where you want to modify/access it? Could you clarify why you don't want to pass the matrices directly to the routines? Fortran is pass by reference so it shouldn't really matter how large the argument is (if this is your concern).

Comment: correct, passing through routines is a non issue, but obviously at 8TB you cant store the whole thing in memory.  Besides structuring your calculation to minimize i/o as best as possible i cant see how you,ll get a generic answer to this question.

Comment: The problem with passing is the memory, as @agentp said.
Well, I guess I'll have to deal with the big files then.
I/O is minimized as much as possible, I thought maybe there was a method I just didn't know about that handles stuff like this better than what I am at the moment doing

Comment: Ah yes I missed the 8TB statement. Depending on what you need to do the data and what machines you have access to, this may be somewhere that mpi can help -- you can distribute the matrix over many machines enabling you to hold the local section in memory.

Comment: @d_1999 parallelization is in place where it is applicable, but the program has to be able to run single-threaded/on one machine.

Comment: I recommend you look into more sophisticated dataio that is built for this type of work. `hdf5` comes to mind for me (https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/)

Comment: @Ross thank you I will look into that!

Comment: So there is an algorithm to compute the needed data on the fly? How demanding is that to do? Have you compared the execution times of using huge files compared to on-the-fly generation? Maybe both are time consuming but one is 100 times less time consuming. Feel free to give more details.